# How to export a table from an oracle database to local computer without using any wizard

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to develop a PL/SQL procedure that will create a final table and export the table in an excel/text file in my local computer automatically. Is there any way to do this? is there any specific command that will export my final table to an excel/text file to my local computer without having to click anything manually?

Comment: Does your local computer have an Oracle instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [`UTL_FILE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm) in Oracle. With `UTL_FILE`, you have great control over the output file format and you seem to need that here and you can easily use `dbms_job` to schedule this procedure to run automatically every day 
at a certain time.

Below is one working example of such procedure from [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:88212348059)

```
create or replace procedure dump_table_to_csv( p_tname in varchar2, p_dir   in varchar2, p_filename in varchar2 )
  is      l_output        utl_file.file_type;
       l_theCursor     integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;
        l_columnValue   varchar2(4000);
        l_status        integer;
        l_query         varchar2(1000)
                       default 'select * from ' || p_tname;
       l_colCnt        number := 0;
       l_separator     varchar2(1);
       l_descTbl       dbms_sql.desc_tab;
   begin
       l_output := utl_file.fopen( p_dir, p_filename, 'w' );
       execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'' ';

       dbms_sql.parse(  l_theCursor,  l_query, dbms_sql.native );
       dbms_sql.describe_columns( l_theCursor, l_colCnt, l_descTbl );

       for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
           utl_file.put( l_output, l_separator || '"' || l_descTbl(i).col_name || '"' );
           dbms_sql.define_column( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue, 4000 );
           l_separator := ',';
       end loop;
       utl_file.new_line( l_output );

       l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_theCursor);

       while ( dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_theCursor) > 0 ) loop
           l_separator := '';
           for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
               dbms_sql.column_value( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue );
               utl_file.put( l_output, l_separator || l_columnValue );
               l_separator := ',';
           end loop;
           utl_file.new_line( l_output );
       end loop;
       dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_theCursor);
       utl_file.fclose( l_output );

       execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-MON-yy'' ';
   exception
       when others then
           execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-MON-yy'' ';
           raise;
   end;
   /
```

This is how you will make the call to this job.

```
exec dump_table_to_csv( 'emp', '/tmp', 'tkyte.emp' );
```