# Immediate Execute for dynamic columns with unknown datatypes and multiple joins in the select query - Oracle stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

From the below query, I am expecting to get the result set into an associative array and run through a loop. This query will have dynamic columns, dynamic tables joined and the datatypes of the columns are unknown.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RULE_TEST AS 
  qry_stmt CLOB;
  type qry_stmt_result_type is table of varchar2(3000) index by binary_integer;
  qry_stmt_result qry_stmt_result_type;
BEGIN
  qry_stmt:='SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3, col_N FROM table_x 
            JOIN on table_x.col_1=table_y.col_5
            JOIN on table_y.col_2=table_z.col_3
            WHERE table_z.col_2 = 1';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE qry_stmt bulk collect into qry_stmt_result;
  
  FOR i IN qry_stmt_result.first..qry_stmt_result.last LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(qry_stmt_result(i));
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(qry_stmt_result(i).col_1);
  END LOOP;        
END RULE_TEST;
```

Comment: In Oracle the resultset always has predefined structure. Target variable should have the same structure. What is the reason to have variable with generictype (which Oracle doesn't allow as long as I know).

Comment: @astentx We are joining many tables and these tables and columns will be decided by the end-user. These tables have large data which will then be moved into another table based on some conditions of each column and result set.

Comment: You could use the `dbms_sql` package to handle an arbitrary SQL statement (realizing that you need to do a lot of work to ensure you're safe from SQL injection attacks).  But you're not going to be able realistically to fetch the data into a single collection.  You could parse, describe the columns, and do array binds to fetch the data.  You could start with this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509018/how-to-export-a-table-from-an-oracle-database-to-local-computer-without-using-an

Comment: Even if you could define a collection dynamically, how would you use it?